# Set up cron and compare the two dates

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I would like to send mail for example 14 hours before the date in the database. How could I do that? How should I set up cron and how to make it in the code to send for exemple 14 hours before the date in the database?

In my database i have cutoffs table (id, datetime, regio_id).

In my code i have for example :

```
    $dt = new DateTime();
    $trenutniDatumiVrijeme = $dt->format('Y-m-d H:m:s');

    $rez = mysqli_query($kon, "SELECT * FROM cutoffs");
    while($red = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rez)){
       $trDatum = strtotime($trenutniDatumiVrijeme);
       $cutOffDatum = strtotime($red["datetime"]);
       if(**it is 14hours to $cutOffDatum???**){
            *send mail*
       }
    }
```

And how should I set up cron to run this file and to send this mail only once? Every hour, every 5 hours, every 14 hours or ....?

My query is :

```
    //Uzimamo podatke za korisnika
            $rezKor = mysqli_query($kon, "SELECT * FROM korisnici WHERE id = ". $user_id ." LIMIT 1");
            $redKor = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rezKor);
            $korEmail = $redKor["email"];
            $naam = $redKor["ime"] . " " . $redKor["prezime"];
            $korPostcode = $redKor["postcode"];

            $trenutniDatum = strtotime($trenutniDatumiVrijeme);

    $rezCutoff = mysqli_query($kon, "SELECT cutoffs.id as cutoff_id, cutoffs.datetime as cutoffTime, regios.id as regioID, regios.naam as regioNaam, regio_deelgemeente_tt.id, deelgemeentes.regio_postcode FROM cutoffs 
INNER JOIN regios ON regios.id = cutoffs.regio_id 
INNER JOIN regio_deelgemeente_tt ON regios.id = regio_deelgemeente_tt.regio_id 
INNER JOIN deelgemeentes ON regio_deelgemeente_tt.deelgemeente_id = deelgemeentes.id 
WHERE deelgemeentes.regio_postcode = ". $korPostcode ." AND cutoffs.datetime > ". $trenutniDatum ." 
GROUP BY cutoffs.regio_id ORDER BY cutoffs.id DESC");
```

I have table cutoffs
[image]

The cutoff with id 7 has already passed, but i still get it in my results.

Comment: wouldn't be easier to take the current time add 14 hours, add a where clause to your query "select * FROM cutoffs where cutoffs.datetime > XYZ

Comment: and you could make sure the cutoff time is within the 5 hour range with an AND)

Comment: I would suggest rather than going for cron job you can use Mysql Event that provide this type of feature....

Comment: @PaulBastide I updated my quesion.

Comment: to send the e-mail only once, mark it in the database with a field "emailSend" yes / no. and in the `SELECT * FROM cutoffs WHERE cutoffs.datetime > XYZ AND emailSend = "no" `

Comment: @mmm Sorry my bad. I need to send the email every week, 14 hours before the datetime field in the cutoff table.

Comment: As it's related to hours it's difficult to run a script. As you have mentioned above that you running a cron weekly , so when cron execute it will check for the date you have stored in the database and get the 14 hours before date time and if that date time is not equal to the current time it will not return anything.